# Contrast Estimates

Tags: contrasts

Question: can I use contrast estimates to test a specific hypothesis if my model estimates are not statistically significant?

I ran a HLM using SAS PROC MIXED where my model involves triple interaction terms. Most of the estimates for the coefficients in my model are NOT statistically significant. However, I ran CONTRAST ESTIMATE statements to test several hypotheses and these estimates were statistically significant. So can I conclude that my hypotheses were supported even though my model estimates are not statistically significant?

Below is an example of what I am trying to do:

$y=\beta_0+\beta_1A+\beta_2B+\beta_3C+\beta_4A*B+\beta_5A*C+\beta_6B*C+\beta_7A*B*C+\epsilon$

Now if majority of my $\beta$ estimates are not statistically significant, but the following hypothesis test (using contrast estimates) was statistically significant (supporting the alternative hypothesis), then is it safe to say that the data support my hypothesis?

$H_0:E[Y|A=a_1, B=b_1,C=c_1]-E[Y|A=a_2, B=b_2,C=c_2]\le0$
$H_A:E[Y|A=a_1, B=b_1,C=c_1]-E[Y|A=a_2, B=b_2,C=c_2]>0$